# Invoke-WebRequest pass url as script argument (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell

I am trying to download file from the web using following command

`Invoke-WebRequest  $url -OutFile   $filePath  -Headers $Headers`

I  have argument, which contains this url and it is passed as parameter

`[string]$artifactHttpAddress = $args[2]`

Currently its value is

`http://10.45.48.26/httpAuth/repository/downloadAll/TeamCityTest_Build/529:id/artifacts.zip`

So, when I try to invoke WebRequest with following command
`Invoke-WebRequest  $artifactHttpAddress -OutFile   c:/test.zip  -Headers $Headers`

it is downloading empty zip file .

but when I try to assign this url to the variable and  invoke web request

```
$url = "http://10.45.48.26/httpAuth/repository/downloadAll/TeamCityTest_Build/529:id/artifacts.zip"
Invoke-WebRequest  $url -OutFile   c:/test.zip  -Headers $Headers
```

It is working correctly, downloads zip file, which have some content in it.

I tried following script

```
Write-Host([string]$url -eq [string]$artifactHttpAddress) 
Write-Host([string]$url) 
Write-Host([string]$artifactHttpAddress)
```

It outputs

```
 False
 http://10.45.48.26/httpAuth/repository/downloadAll/TeamCityTest_Build/528:id/artifacts.zip
 http://10.45.48.26/httpAuth/repository/downloadAll/TeamCityTest_Build/531:id/artifacts.zip
```

What is happening and why?

p.s. this script is inside `ScriptBlock`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me, based on your output, that `$url` and `$artifactHttpAddress` are not the same value. Does the ZIP file exist at the URL with 531 in it?

Comment: That was issue I think, missed difference between urls